# Find multiple regex matches within a certain section

Tags: python, regex

I already searched for this and found some posts, but none of them actually solved my issue.

I have the body of an email. Which goes something like this:

```
From: sender@example.com
Sent Date: Monday, 31.12.99 8:30:12
To: Name of Recp1 <recipient1@example.com>, Name of Recp2 <recipient2@example.com>, Name of Recp3 <recipient3@example.com>
```

text...

No I want to have a regex expression which only extracts all the recipients...

But when I do something like:

```
<(\w+(?:\.?\w+)@\w+\.\w{2,3})>
```

I find all the email addresses including the sender address.

But when I do something like:

```
To:.*<(\w+(?:\.?\w+)@\w+\.\w{2,3})>
```

I only find the last recipient.

How can I say, find all the email addresses starting with To:

I also tried it with the starting ancor ^ but then it doesn't match anything

```
^To:.*<(\w+(?:\.?\w+)@\w+\.\w{2,3})>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: With `To:.*<(\w+(?:\.?\w+)@\w+\.\w{2,3})>`, you only get the *last* email. What is the language?

Comment: Are the spaces before and after the brackets suppose to be there? `< recipient1@example.com >,`

Comment: yes because otherwise here in stackoverflow when I write it without the spaces the whole expression disappeared
So there are NO spaces in the original body

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes you are right, it is the last recipient, sorry my fault.

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do, is first find the whole line that starts with `To:` and then use the pattern to get the email addresses.

```
import re

regex = r"^To: .*"

test_str = ("From: sender@example.com\n"
            "Sent Date: Monday, 31.12.99 8:30:12\n"
            "To: Name of Recp1 <recipient1@example.com>, Name of Recp2 <recipient2@example.com>, Name of Recp3 <recipient3@example.com>")

for m in re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE):
    print(re.findall(r"\w+\.?\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3}", m))
```

Output

```
['recipient1@example.com', 'recipient2@example.com', 'recipient3@example.com']
```

If you can use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you could make use of a lookbehind

```
(?<=^To:.*)\w+\.?\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I6sPXe/1) | [Python demo](https://rextester.com/RMDEX2687)

Comment: yep, already did exactly the same "workaround". 
But I just thought there is a solution with one single regex expression. 
But ok, this is fine too!